# Replace Duplicate String Characters

Tags: python, string, replace, duplicates, iteration

I need to convert a string `word` where each character that appears only once should be appear as `'('` in the new string. Any duplicate characters in the original string should be replaced with `')'`.

My code below...

```
def duplicate_encode(word):
new_word = ''
for char in word:
    if len(char) > 1:
        new_word += ')'
    else:
        new_word += '('
return new_word
```

The test I'm not passing is as follows:

'((((((' should equal '()()()'

This would suggest that, if for example, the input is "recede," the output should read `()()()`.

Comment: If the test is such that '((((((' should turn into '()()()', what you should be trying to do is for each character, turn it into '(' except if the character is identical to the one preceding it, in which case it should be turned into ')'. 'Recede', as well as most English words, would remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Your Code is Good just need some alteration it will be great.

```
def duplicate_encode(word):
    """
    To replace the duplicate letter with ")" in a string.
    if given letter is unique it replaced with "("
    """
    word_dict = {}   # initialize a dictionary
    new_word = "" 
    for i in set(word):   # this loop is used to count duplicate words
        word_count = word.count(i)
        word_dict[i] = word_count   # add letter and count of the letter to dictionary
    for i in word:
        if word_dict[i] > 1:
            new_word += ")"
        else:
            new_word += "("
    print new_word

duplicate_encode("recede")
```

I think you got the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Just because (it's late and) it's possible:

```
def duplicate_encode(word):

    return (lambda w: ''.join(('(', ')')[c in w[:i] + w[i+1:]] for i, c in enumerate(w)))(word.lower())

print(duplicate_encode("rEcede"))
```

OUTPUT

```
> python3 test.py
()()()
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your result is based on the number of occurrences of a character in the word, you can use `Counter` to keep track of that:

```
def duplicate_encode(word):
    from collections import Counter

    word = word.lower()              # to disregard case
    counter = Counter(word)
    new_word = ''
    for char in word:
        if counter[char] > 1:        # if the character appears more than once in the word 
                                     # translate it to )
            new_word += ')'
        else:
            new_word += '('
    return new_word

duplicate_encode('recede')
# '()()()'
```

Comment: This is super useful! i forgot to mention that i want to ensure my function also disregards case. So, take "Success" - that should return )())()).

Comment: You can convert the word to lower case with the `.lower()` method. See the update.